# Does sscanf support boolean type?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to get from a string a boolean value. the string looks like that:

```
char *s = "value=TRUE";
```

the value could be `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `true` or `false`

I m wondering if there is a format specifier to get directly the boolean value from the string? I do not need to pass throught a string and then deduce the boolean value.

I m looking for something like that

```
bool x;
sscanf(s,"value=%b",&x);
```

the question is. Is it possible to get the bool value directly with sscanf and with a format specifier?

If not, Are there a quick method for that?

**Edit:**

Based on the response there is no direct format specifier.

Here a after a quick method to get the boolean value directelly

```
char b[8];
if ( sscanf(s,"value=%[TtRrUuEe]",b))
   return TRUE;
else
   return FALSE;
```

I know that the above method is limited. How ameliorate it?

Note: the default value is False in case the value string contains garbage

Comment: I'd take the chance to point out that `bool` is not a typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the short answer is "no".

You could get the source for GNU C-library and change that for yourself.

f.e.

```
mysscanf(char *buf, char *format, ...)
{
  // scan the format for %b and change it to %s and 
  // redirect the equivalent paramter-variable
  // to a char * buffer
  // then analyse the buffer and write the boolean value into the original parameter
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "glibc"?  There's "glib" and "glibc", and they are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
char b[8];
if ( sscanf(s,"value=%[TtRrUuEe]",b))
   return TRUE;
else
   return FALSE;
```

Comment: This will crash.  You have to allocate the space for string specifiers to store data.

Comment: This will also match things like `uterus` (leaving the trailing `s` behind), not just all case-variants of `true`.

Comment: I know that's why I m looking here to ameliorate the format specifier

Answer (score 0):

No you have to read the value to **char and then lowercase the value you've read, compare it to to "true" using strcmp(). if it matches, than affect true to your bool variable.